# Can Web Essentials 2013 compile markdown to HTML with a template?

Tags: markdown, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials 2013 with VS2013.

I have a .md file that I use to write documentation about a service. The preview works fine, I even used `WE-Markdown.css` and `WE-Markdown.html` for a prettier preview. But when it compiles to HTML (using the "Web Essentials -> Compile Markdown to HTML" context menu option), it simply generates the equivalent output with any `<html>` or `<body>` tag.

Is there a way to tell it to compile it the same way it generates the preview?

Otherwise, I'll have to change my project's build to compile the markdown with something else using the template.

I tried opening the source, but I can't load the solution with VS2013 (or I'm missing some SDKs). I can't find where the compilation occurs in the source on GitHub either.

Comment: I don't know anything about "Web Essentials" (thus a comment rather than an answer), but it is the norm for Markdown parsers to not produce an entire document. If you think of Markdown as being a "document fragment" it helps. A few Markdown parsers will offer the option to wrap the output in a document, but it is rare. In fact, I see it as a bug if a parser does not give me a fragment by default. I always assume the parser will not and expect to need to do that myself. I have found that the tools which do offer the option give me output I can't use anyway. I always create my own wrapper.

Comment: I ended up writing a PowerShell script that uses the WE-Markdown.html template that WebEssentials uses and ran the script on a post-build event. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @ChristianDroulers: Would you mind posting an answer to your question about how you did this? I would be interested in doing this as well.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I will! I forgot about this question! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a PowerShell script that does the compilation + templating and calling it in a post-build event.

Here it is :

```
PARAM(
    [string]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    $MarkdownPath,
    [string]
    $Title
)

$MarkdownPath = Resolve-Path $MarkdownPath;

if (-not $Title)
{
    $Title = $MarkdownPath;
}

# Adjust this to your solution. There might be a better way to find WE-Markdown.html
$solutionPath = Resolve-Path $PSScriptRoot;

# Same for packages path
$cmarkExe = (Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $solutionPath .\packages\**\cmark.exe) -Recurse)[0].FullName;
$out = $MarkdownPath.Replace(".md", ".html");

$compiled = & $cmarkExe $MarkdownPath | Out-String;

$template = Get-Content (Join-Path $solutionPath WE-Markdown.html) -Encoding UTF8 -Raw;

$result = $template -replace "{##TITLE##}", $Title `
    -replace "{##SOLUTION_PATH_PLACEHOLDER##}", $solutionPath `
    -replace "{##PROJECT_PATH_PLACEHOLDER##}", "" `
    -replace "{##DOCUMENT_PATH_PLACEHOLDER##}", $MarkdownPath `
    -replace "{##MARKDOWN_HTML_PLACEHOLDER##}", $compiled `
    -replace "language-C#", "csharp"; # Replace any other thing that is relevant to your project

Set-Content -Path $out -Value $result -Encoding UTF8;
```

And here is a github repository with everything https://github.com/cdroulers/webessentials-markdown-template

And a sample Post-build event:

```
PowerShell.exe $(SolutionDir)Generate-Documentation.ps1 $(ProjectDir)docs\*.md Web_Page_Title_Here
```

Comment: @GregBurghardt Here it is! Once you get it working, please contribute any interesting changes you've done!

Comment: Will do. I'm going to dig into this on Tuesday. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you save this PowerShell script to? And can you show an example call to the script from your Post build event?

Comment: I got it working. I also added a sample post build event to your answer. 
+1

Comment: I just realized this only works with one file at a time. I've forked your GitHub repository. I'll try my hand and multiple files getting parsed.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It should be a simple "foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem $MarkdownPath))". Waiting for that PR!